# PPTP pass through on Cisco ASA 5505 (8.2)

Tags: nat, pptp, cisco-asa

Is it possible to setup PPTP VPN traffic (clients outside and server inside) to passthrough a Cisco ASA 5505 if the outside IP address is also being used for PAT?

The Cisco examples forward all NAT traffic from the outside to the inside VPN server.  I only have one IP available currently and need PAT.

Answer (score 5):

The stock ASA configuration does not include support for PPTP passthrough by default -- crazy as to why.  Cisco TAC likely gets a handful of cases related to this...

There are at most three things required to get PPTP working through an ASA

*If server is behind ASA*

1. Configure necessary NAT/PAT if using NAT/PAT (Optional but usually required)
2. ACL permit TCP/1723 to server/IP (whether real, mapped, or interface depends on ASA version)
3. Enable PPTP inspection

   - Explicit ACL permit for GRE is ***not*** necessary

*If client is behind ASA*

1. Enable PPTP inspection

**Server example**

- ASA outside interface IP 1.1.1.2/30
- Server inside IP 10.0.0.10/24
- Static PAT (port forwarding) TCP/1723 using ASA outside interface IP

***ASA 8.3 and newer (with focus on objects)***

```
object network hst-10.0.0.10
 description Server
 host 10.0.0.10
object network hst-10.0.0.10-tcp1723
 description Server TCP/1723 Static PAT Object
 host 10.0.0.10
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 1723 1723

object-group service svcgrp-10.0.0.10 tcp
 port-object eq 1723

access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object hst-10.0.0.10 object-group svcgrp-10.0.0.10-tcp
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside

class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic

policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect pptp

service-policy global_policy global
```

***ASA 8.2 and prior***

```
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any interface outside eq 1723

access-group outside_access_in in interface outside

static (inside,outside) tcp interface 1723 10.0.0.10 1723 netmask 255.255.255.255

class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic

policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect pptp

service-policy global_policy global
```

**Client example**

Valid for all ASA OS versions

```
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic

policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect pptp

service-policy global_policy global
```

If these examples don't fit your scenario post your specifics and we can customize a config for you.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen. All versions, both directions. Very well done. Small question: In the server example, ASA 8.3, when you refer to "object hst-10.0.0.10" in the access-list, shouldn't that be "object hst-10.0.0.10-tcp1723"? Should we refer to the object with the nat, or just the server in general? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @JamesNewton Technically it doesn't matter since the host defined in both hst-10.0.0.10 and hst-10.0.0.10-tcp1723 objects is the same. However, I would recommend using the objects as indicated given the ASA's wonky way of static PAT in ASA 8.3+. The hst-10.0.0.10 object is used to define the host in an ACL's ACE. The svcgrp-10.0.0.10-tcp object is used to define all ports permitted (can contain multiple ports in the same object). The hst-10.0.0.10-tcp1723 object is never used in ACL - it is only used to define the static PAT behavior, one object per port needed - ASA limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly possible (and how I use PPTP here).

1. Create a firewall rule on the access list thats bound to your OUTSIDE interface to allow any incoming packets using pptp to pass.
2. Create a NAT rule on the inside interface that redirects all incoming packets on the pptp port to an internal server

Comment: I have done this, plus allowed GRE traffic as well, but it still isn't working. I can see hits on the PPTP rule when making connection attempts, but nothing is hitting the GRE rule.

Comment: Cisco ASA has a protocol proxy for PPTP, you should not need to forward GRE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also "inspect" the PPTP traffic.  Adding that fixed the problem for me.